# Unknown Syntax errors in linkedlist Sort program

Tags: c++

Assignment was to create a sort function for linked list. Was able to code it, but I am getting a ton of unknown syntax errors. I suspect it could be Visual Studio (professor requires it), but I want to see what you guys think. Most of the errors lie in the header file (SortedList.h), however my professor provided this piece of code, so it doesnt make sense that it doesnt work.

```
EDIT:
Errors include:
-Missing type specifier - int assumed Note: C++ does not support default int 
(sortedlist.h Line:4)
-Syntax error missing ; before identifier ItemType (sortedlist.h Line:4)
-'string' ambiguous symbol (sortedlistprogram.cpp Line:12)
-Syntax error: Identifier 'itemType' (Sortedlist.h Line 14)
-Unexpected token(s) proceeding ';' (sortedlist.h Line 34)



//SortedList.h (header file)
#include <string>
const int MAX_ITEMS = 20;
typedef string ItemType;
class SortedList
{
public:
  SortedList();
  // Constructor
  // Post: Empty list is created.

  // Action responsibilities
  void Insert(ItemType item);
  // Pre:  The list is not full; 
  // Post: item is in the list; list is stored in
  //       increasing order.
  void PrintList();
  // Post: If the list is not empty, the elements are
  //       printed on the screen in increasing order; 
  //       otherwise "The list is empty" is
  //       printed on the screen.

  // Knowledge responsibilities
  int GetLength();
  // Post: return value is the number of items in the list.
  bool IsEmpty();
  // Post: returns true if list is empty; false otherwise.
  bool IsFull();
  // Post: returns true if there is no more room in the
  //       list; false otherwise.
private:
   int length;
   ItemType values[MAX_ITEMS];
};
//SortedList.CPP
#include "sortedList.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
SortedList::SortedList()
{
   length = 0;
}
bool SortedList::IsEmpty()
//Function to check if empty
{
  if (values->empty())
       return true;
    return false;
}
 bool SortedList::IsFull()
 //Function to check if full
{
    if (length == MAX_ITEMS)
        return true;
     return false;
 }
void SortedList::Insert(ItemType item)
//Insert function for SortedList
{
    if (!IsFull())
    {
    values[length] = item;
    ++length;
    sort(values, values + length);
   }
}
int SortedList::GetLength()
//Function to return length
{
    return length;
}
void SortedList::PrintList()
//Function to print list
{
    if (IsEmpty())
    {
       cout << "List is empty" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < length; ++index)
    {
        cout << values[index] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << "There are " << GetLength() << " items in the list" << 
   endl;
  }
}
//Driver.CPP
#include "sortedList.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string value;
SortedList list;
list.PrintList();
ifstream file("word.in");
//calls word.in file
if (file.good())
    //Checks if file is good
{
    while (getline(file, value))
    {
        list.Insert(value);
    }
    file.close();
}
list.PrintList();
//Prints list

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the first few errors? In many cases, there is really just one error (the first one reported) and the rest are cascade errors.

Comment: Please post the actual error text (not a screenshot!) so that we can see what is what. Oh, and add `std::` to `typedef string ItemType;`, which might be the source of your errors.

Comment: The program compiles as is (just removed the `sortedList` import and added `std::` to the `string` `typedef`). What issue are you having?

Comment: After fixing the `typedef` (as Ken Y-N pointed out), Godbolt seems fine with your code: https://godbolt.org/g/xd3yxD.

Comment: Also, `values->empty()` is not correct if you first do `Insert("")`.

Comment: Hmmm.. It is possible that I am using a different Windows SDK version than what I use at school. Apparently (after just checking) I am suppose to use 8.1, and I am using 10.0.1. Do you think that could be the issue?

Comment: *Most of the errors lie in the header file (SortedList.h), however my professor provided this piece of code, so it doesnt make sense that it doesnt work.* Your professor's code isn't really correct, as has been pointed out by @Ken

Comment: Windows SDK version shouldn't make a difference, but compiler version certainly will; your school might possibly have an ancient version of Visual Studio from before namespaces were introduced...